# Define a two-dimensional, square array of ints and calculate the sum

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm just a beginner in Java. I've got the task:

Define a two-dimensional, square array of ints and then calculate and print the sum of all elements on the main diagonal. No modifications of your program should be necessary when the array (in particular its dimensions) is modified.

And this is what I came up with:

```
public class Problem1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] a = {
            {10, 10, 8},
            {8, 10, 10},
            {10, 10, 8}
        };
        int sum = 0;
        for (int counter = 0; counter < a.length; counter++) {
            sum += a[counter][counter];
        }

        System.out.println("the sum is " + sum);
    }
}
```

Of course, I did it wrong but I cannot find any other solution on the internet.
Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: What is wrong with it?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: This looks like a school assignment - maybe you should work to understand it yourself.

Comment: It is working absolutely fine. what problem are you facing?

Comment: looks good to me.

Comment: a lack of code self confidence ?

Comment: Do you have any test cases that don't work?

Answer (score 0):

you should have two for loops in order to move in a 2D array
try this:

```
for(int i= 0; i <a.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++){
        if(i == j){
            sum = sum + a[i][i] ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you mean `sum = sum +a[i];` ?

Comment: `sum += a[i][i];` or `a[j][j] since i == j`

Comment: What is this approach supposed to buy you?

Comment: I suppose the only thing it caters for if it is not a square array @biziclop

Comment: @Fubar I suppose it does, but in quite an inefficient way. And the task says nothing about handling non-square arrays.